# Sed command not working as expected for delete particular line from file

Tags: linux, bash, sed, centos

I have try to use `sed` command for delete particular line from file but it seems not working properly in my system (CentOS release 6.3 (Final).

my file1.txt contain following data

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
```

Now i try below command to delete 3rd line from the file.

```
$ sed '3d' file1.txt
```

And output of above command is

```
line1
line2
line4
line5
```

But when i check original file then it seems nothing deleted. 3rd line is there.

So any one have idea why `sed` not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make it in-line sed:

```
sed -i.bak '3d' file1.txt
```

Comment: ok it works, so basically `sed` command works safely means first it take backup of original file then delete from original right?..Thanks lot

Comment: Yes that's correct, you will see original file backup with `.bak` extension.

Comment: @anubhava:But this command will not work in busybox's sed you should use sed -i '3d' file1.txt instead

Comment: I cant test on busybox but usually sed commands allow a backup extension for safety purpose.

Comment: `sed -i '3d' file1.txt` also works without taking backup of original.

Answer (score 1):

To delete particular lines from a file using `sed` without creating a backup:

```sh
sed -i '' -e '3,6d' file1.txt
```

The command above will remove lines 3 up to and including 6 from `file1.txt`, without creating a backup